# How to speed up spark's parquet reader with many small files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I'm reading in a spark dataframe that's stored in the parquet format on the local cluster's HDFS.  The parquet data is split among approx 96,000 individual files.  Now I know that ideally the data wouldn't be split into so many small files, but for now I've got to deal with it in this format.  I'm using pyspark v2.2.0.

When I run `spark.read.parquet(data_root)`, something strange happens: spark sequentially spawns a series of jobs, each with about 2000 tasks.  It spawns up 48 of these jobs, each with one stage. Across these 48 jobs it executes just around 96,000 tasks - I assume it runs a task for each parquet file.  Each job only takes about 2 seconds to run.

The thing I find strange is that this doesn't happen in one job with 96,000 tasks, because that would be faster (no stage boundaries).  Where does the number 2000 come from?  Is there a parameter I can tune to force more of these tiny tasks into the same job, thereby speeding things up?

Comment: You can use `parquet-tools` to merge all of them together first and then use Spark to read it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of Spark2.0. [FileSourceStrategy](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileSourceStrategy.scala) Combines the smaller parquet files to make a larger file so that it can work in optimized way. Ideally each spark executor wants to work on a block size equivalent to the HDFS block size (128MB).

Comment: Do you know of any spark parameters I can use to tweak this to happen in fewer jobs?

Comment: I saw some parameters which you can tweak to stop this. However didn't use them. Just check the code link I pasted there are some parameters which you can pass from spark conf

Comment: Looking at line 141-150, it looks like `defaultMaxSplitBytes`, `openCostInBytes`, and `bytesPerCore` control the split size by setting it to `min(defaultMaxSplitBytes, max(openCostInBytes, bytesPerCore))`.  If you explain how this fits together in your answer, then I'll accept it (after testing).  Otherwise I'll do that and write up my own answer.

Comment: Also, an ideal answer would include an explanation of what's going on behind the scenes (what happens in each job, and why there are so many jobs).

Comment: I've tried tweaking `defaultMaxSplitBytes`, `openCostInBytes`, and `bytesPerCore` (via tweaks to default parallelism) and none of those tweaks had any effect on the problem.